# I can I fix my code which is returning an empty array from a function and has no error messages

Tags: php

I have a problem where a function is returning an empty. I am trying to show results from a database to a table using the foreach loop . (see code). I know this array is empty because I used the print_r($array) to see what the function is returning and there was just a string  "Array()"...

**the function**

```
function day_to_day_report(){
    require_once('database.php');
    global $db;
    $date = '"2020-01-02"';
    $paid = '"Y"';
    $clientID = 'C.Client_id';
    $query = 'SELECT I.CLIENT_ID , CONCAT( C.C_NAME," ", C.C_SURNAME ) , I.INV_NUM , I.INV_DATE 
    FROM tblinv_info I, tblclientinfo C
    WHERE I.inv_date < :date AND I.INV_PAID <> :paid AND I.Client_id = :clientId
    ORDER BY I.Inv_Date ASC ';
    $statement1 = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement1->bindValue(':date',$date);
    $statement1->bindValue(':paid',$paid);
    $statement1->bindValue(':clientId', $clientID);
    $statement1->execute();
    $day_to_day = $statement1->fetchAll();
    $statement1->CloseCursor();
    
    return $day_to_day;
    }
```

This function returns no error messages and no data from the database.

**the foreach code to display the table**

```
foreach($day_to_days as $dayReport) : 
                    <tr>
                        <td>1<?php echo "$dayReport[0]"; ?></td>
                        <td>2<?php echo "$dayReport[1]"; ?></td>
                        <td>3<?php echo "$dayReport[2]"; ?></td>
                        <td>4<?php echo "$dayReport[3]"; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
            endforeach;        
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check with `mysqli_affected_rows` first. Maybe theres no error with your code but you dont have an item from db to show.

Comment: I've never seen this before how and where do I use it?

Comment: you can read [PHP Documentations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 0):

your have returned $day_to_day
but in foreach loop you types $day_to_days
Replace with below code

```
foreach($day_to_day as $dayReport) : 
                        <tr>
                            <td>1<?php echo "$dayReport[0]"; ?></td>
                            <td>2<?php echo "$dayReport[1]"; ?></td>
                            <td>3<?php echo "$dayReport[2]"; ?></td>
                            <td>4<?php echo "$dayReport[3]"; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php              
   endforeach;        
      }
```

Comment: I did that and still the same.

Comment: echo query statement and check in mysql console whether it displays data or not

Comment: did that and still no joy

Comment: put $statement1->CloseCursor(); after return $day_to_day;